# Xamarin ExportFont cause Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found FontAwesome.ttf

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using the new feature from Xamarin.Forms for export font its working just nice in iOS but it fail in android with that crash

here are my steps

1. Add a TTF or OTF file from Google Fonts, FontAwesome,
   etc. as an embedded resource in your shared project
2. Add the ExportFont attribute to your assembly. e.g. [assembly:
       ExportFont("FontAwesome.ttf", Alias = "FontAwesome")]
3. Reference the font family in XAML markup
4. Compile and run the Android app

the error stack

```
JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args)
    JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters)
    Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Android.Content.Res.AssetManager mgr, System.String path)
    FontExtensions.CreateTypeface (System.Tuple`2[T1,T2] key) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\FontExtensions.cs:177
    ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs:1002
    FontExtensions.ToTypeface (System.String fontFamily, Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes fontAttributes) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\FontExtensions.cs:161
    FontExtensions.ToTypeface (Xamarin.Forms.Font self) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\FontExtensions.cs:136
    LabelRenderer.UpdateFont () D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\FastRenderers\LabelRenderer.cs:330
    LabelRenderer.UpdateText () D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\FastRenderers\LabelRenderer.cs:426
    LabelRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\FastRenderers\LabelRenderer.cs:259
    LabelRenderer.set_Element (Xamarin.Forms.Label value) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\FastRenderers\LabelRenderer.cs:81
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\FastRenderers\LabelRenderer.cs:166
    Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Android.Content.Context context) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean sameChildren) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:140
    VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.Load () D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:112
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:457
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:244
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:134
    Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Android.Content.Context context) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean sameChildren) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:140
    VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.Load () D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:112
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:457
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:244
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:134
    Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Android.Content.Context context) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean sameChildren) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:140
    VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.Load () D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:112
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:457
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:244
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:134
    Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Android.Content.Context context) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean sameChildren) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:140
    VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.Load () D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:112
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:457
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:244
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:134
    Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Android.Content.Context context) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:350
    ScrollViewContainer.set_ChildView (Xamarin.Forms.View value) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ScrollViewContainer.cs:35
    ScrollViewRenderer.LoadContent () D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ScrollViewRenderer.cs:368
    ScrollViewRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ScrollViewRenderer.cs:101
    Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Android.Content.Context context) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean sameChildren) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:140
    VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.Load () D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:112
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:457
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:244
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:134
    Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, Android.Content.Context context) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, System.Boolean sameChildren) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:140
    VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:350
    VisualElementPackager.Load () D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:112
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:457
    VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:244
    IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:134
    Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager, Android.Content.Context context) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:397
    FragmentContainer.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FragmentContainer.cs:64
    Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_inflater, System.IntPtr native_container, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) D:\a\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release\monoandroid90\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:1903
    (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.50(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found FontAwesome.ttf
    android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset Typeface.java:784
    crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.FragmentContainer.n_onCreateView(Native Method)
    crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.FragmentContainer.onCreateView FragmentContainer.java:41
    androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView Fragment.java:2600
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState FragmentManagerImpl.java:881
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303
    androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps BackStackRecord.java:439
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613
    androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated Fragment.java:2624
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState FragmentManagerImpl.java:904
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238
    androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps BackStackRecord.java:434
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696
    androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss BackStackRecord.java:299
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate FragmentPagerAdapter.java:235
    androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate ViewPager.java:1244
    androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate ViewPager.java:1092
    androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure ViewPager.java:1622
    android.view.View.measure View.java:22071
    crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.TabbedPageRenderer.n_onLayout(Native Method)
    crc64720bb2db43a66fe9.TabbedPageRenderer.onLayout TabbedPageRenderer.java:73
    android.view.View.layout View.java:19659
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout ViewGroup.java:6075
    com.xamarin.forms.platform.android.FormsViewGroup.measureAndLayout FormsViewGroup.java:37
    crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.n_onLayout(Native Method)
    crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.onLayout PlatformRenderer.java:63
    android.view.View.layout View.java:19659
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout ViewGroup.java:6075
    android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout RelativeLayout.java:1083
    android.view.View.layout View.java:19659
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout ViewGroup.java:6075
    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren FrameLayout.java:323
    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout FrameLayout.java:261
    android.view.View.layout View.java:19659
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout ViewGroup.java:6075
    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren FrameLayout.java:323
    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout FrameLayout.java:261
    android.view.View.layout View.java:19659
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout ViewGroup.java:6075
    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren FrameLayout.java:323
    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout FrameLayout.java:261
    android.view.View.layout View.java:19659
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout ViewGroup.java:6075
    android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame LinearLayout.java:1791
    android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical LinearLayout.java:1635
    android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout LinearLayout.java:1544
    android.view.View.layout View.java:19659
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout ViewGroup.java:6075
    android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren FrameLayout.java:323
    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout FrameLayout.java:261
    com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout DecorView.java:761
    android.view.View.layout View.java:19659
    android.view.ViewGroup.layout ViewGroup.java:6075
    android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout ViewRootImpl.java:2496
    android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals ViewRootImpl.java:2212
    android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal ViewRootImpl.java:1392
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run ViewRootImpl.java:6752
    android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run Choreographer.java:911
    android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks Choreographer.java:723
    android.view.Choreographer.doFrame Choreographer.java:658
    android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run Choreographer.java:897
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback Handler.java:790
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage Handler.java:99
    android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:164
    android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:6494
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run RuntimeInit.java:438
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main ZygoteInit.java:807
```

Comment: Can you please share us a Minimal, Reproducible Example? I tried the [custom font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#use-a-custom-font) many times and it always works on my side. Are you using Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.530 or higher?

Comment: any update on this issue? can you provide a way to reproduce with the latest Xamarin.Forms version ?